# webView:didFailLoadWithError - (null) phone gap app for ios

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, uiwebview, invalid-argument

I'm getting this error while loading paypal checkout page. I'm using in app browser of phonegap for this.Any idea?

```
webView:didFailLoadWithError - (null)
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same problem. The resolution is being discussed in the cordova forum https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3530.

Comment: I've just tried one of the suggestions on the cordova forum and it worked for me.   Edit CDVWebViewDelegate.m and comment out lines 199 to 201.

Comment: no probs.  It seems phonegap 2.8 (just released) fixes it too.https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3530